# Powerpoint VBA: Open Source of Linked Excel Chart

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation with several Excel charts pasted as links. Using VBA, I have checked, and the type of these shapes is `msoLinkedOLEObject`.

Knowing this, I would like to first open the Excel file that contains the original chart through VBA and then use the "update link" command of the chart, like this:

[image]

I wish to open the workbooks first because using the "update link" command with an open Excel file is usually faster for me than just using the "update link" command directly (maybe because some PowerPoint presentations and some workbooks are really extense).

For the `sld.Shapes(i).LinkFormat` part of the code, I can use `.UpdateLinks` to directly refresh the data, but I cannot find any way to directly open the Excel source file (in the same way I can by manually clicking the linked chart).

Could this be achieved?

```
Sub UpdateExcelLinkedCharts()
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

Set pres = Application.ActivePresentation

'Loop through all active slides in the presentation
For Each sld In pres.Slides
If sld.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then

'If the slide is a msoLinkedOLEObject, proceed to update its link
For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.Count

If sld.Shapes(i).Type = 10 Then
sld.Shapes(i).LinkFormat.UpdateLinks

End If

Next i

End If

Next sld


MsgBox ("All Links Updated!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

```
sld.Shapes(i).OLEFormat.Activate
```

Or

```
sld.Shapes(i).OLEFormat.DoVerb
```

followed by `sld.Shapes(i).LinkFormat.Update`

Both will open the linked object so you can edit it. But notice that this is not enough to have a reference to an Excel Object that you can manipulate through VBA.